# SwiftuUI NavigationLink inside touchBar

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'm trying to create NavigationLink in MacBook touchBar with help of SwiftUI. Actually with my piece of code, the button is shown in touchbar, but unfortunately the link doesn't work.

```
NavigationView {
  .touchBar {
    NavigationLink(destination: BookView()) {
      Text("GoToBook")
    }
  }
}

struct BookView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Hello")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instead with `Button` in touchBar activating `NavigationLink` programmatically, like below

```
@State private var isActive = false

...

// below in body
NavigationView {
  SomeView()      // << your view here 
  .background(NavigationLink(destination: BookView(), isActive: $isActive) { 
                EmptyView() 
              }  // hidden link
  )
  .touchBar {
     Button("GoToBook") { self.isActive.toggle() } // activate link
  }
}
```

Comment: It will work. Ach, SwiftUI is great, but so bugged :/